# Turn on Wifi and WifiHotspot together in Android Smartphone

Tags: android, wifi

Currently we can share only Mobile's Data Internet. Once Wifi is turned On hotspot will be disabled and vice versa.

Is it possible to turn on both Wifi and Wifi hotspot together so that we can share mobile's internet which is already connected to wifi.

Kindly give your suggestions....

Comment: It's not. Maybe if you have root acess.

Comment: Both cant be used together AFAIK

Comment: Wait. Is this a development question? Or is this a _how to use this feature_ question?

Comment: Its for development purpose. If it is possible I will develop an App..

Answer (score 2):

Nonesense. WISP bridges over the same physical radio while maintaining two virtually (software) defined networks, essentially they are VLANs on the same interface, often 2.4g. Should the objection be the use of one radio for two functions, then there is no excuse not to have the Internet connection on one radio band and the local "behind the router" LAN on the other. Routers are not magic. Nearly all consumer grade routers share the same, or nearly same, embedded Linux kernel and support tools. Root and go deep enough for this must be possible. Maybe not easy to reverse engineer but possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depend on the hardware type also, I have ASUS Pro P2430UA. With it I can connect to the my phone wifi and at same time, I can create hotspot in the laptop for sharing internet to others.

Hardware qualcomm atheros qac9377.

Answer (score 0):

Your device has radio transmitters/receivers built in that provide you different types of signals such as wifi, Bluetooth, etc. When you turn on your hotspot, the radios that handle wifi change from a state that allows you to access another wifi radio to a mode that make YOU the provider of wifi. The wifi radios can't do both at the same time.

Comment: Good explanation. Whether is it possible to share wifi internet using bluetooth ?

Comment: take a look at this link https://www.androidpit.com/share-wifi-over-bluetooth

Comment: nonsense. a single wifi adapter can both send and receive at the same time albeit with half bandwidth only and fixed channel.

Answer (score 0):

At a time, a wireless card can either work as a host(access point) or client. Since our current generation phones only have one WiFi adapter, its not practically possible as of now.

An alternative suggestion would be to tether your WiFi using bluetooth.

Comment: the question was specifically aimed at android phones and I don't understand how your comment makes sense.